# How to use resource files

Tags: localization, resource-files

Plenty of links, no definitive answer found. How to use localizable resource files and change the current locale for a user under sharepoint AND external apps.

I have global resources deployed with my solution. The default invariant file works absolutely fine, but when I set the user's locale to something different, the locale is not being picked up.

Do we need satelite assemblies? I see VS2010 is creating folders and dlls under the bin directory one for each culture variant - but with the same name!? So [this post](http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/deploying-localized-satellite-assemblies-with-sharepoint-2010/#comment-1179) is erroneous as u cant add the same dll name to the package.

I would like to be able to load the resources from the dll so that other apps (services/consoles) can also access these resources.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("zh-HK");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("zh-HK");
object o = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("myAppResources", "FRONT_PAGE_INTRO");
```

This is what VS2010 has in the manifest:

```
 <ApplicationResourceFiles>
    <App_GlobalResourceFile Location="myApp\myAppResources.resx" />
    <App_GlobalResourceFile Location="myApp\myAppResources.zh-HK.resx" />
  </ApplicationResourceFiles>
```

and

```
<Assembly Location="myApp.resources.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be where I was registering the locale, this needs to be in the PreRequestHandler not the BeginRequest one.

```
application.PreRequestHandlerExecute += SetLocale;
```

not

```
application.BeginRequest += SetLocale;

private void SetLocale(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LocalizationHelper.SetThreadCurrentCulture();
}
```

Obvious!